# Converting audio file time to string and to date

Tags: android, time

I am getting my audio file length converting it to string and then using SipleDataFormat("mm:ss")

I am getting right time and i am converting it to string easliy.

I am using this code:

```
            int length = mp.getDuration()/1000;
            mp.release();

            SimpleDateFormat simpledata = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");

            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mmss");

            String audiotime = String.valueOf(length);
            String datenow=String.valueOf(length);

            Date date2 = null;
            try {
                date2 = (Date) formatter.parse(datenow);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String filetime = simpledata.format(date2);
            textView1.setText(filetime);
```

When i want to convert String like "1201" its work correct i just cant convert my file time, i dont know time of this file is 5140ms but when i am converting it to sec its 5 s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateFormat` doesn't really work for this as it is not a date you are passing to it but a length of time. It's simpler to just calculate the minutes and seconds given the duration.

`MediaPlayer.getDuration()` returns the length of the audio in milliseconds (1/1000th of a second). So 5140 milliseconds is 5.14 seconds.

You can use this to format your duration:

```
public static String getTimeString(long duration) {
    int minutes = (int) Math.floor(duration / 1000 / 60);
    int seconds = (int) ((duration / 1000) - (minutes * 60));
    return minutes + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds);
}
```

Then when you need the string:

```
String timeString = getTimeString(mp.getDuration());
textView1.setText(timeString);
```